# Query new data based on combobox, and display it in new textbox

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a combobox that contains a project number id. Based on the selection of this combobox I want to display the amount of rows in another table containing the same project number id. This value will be appended to the blue box "Number of POs".

[image: Image of Form]

My file "new-customer-po.php". I'll display it in parts for simplicity.

```
<?php
//Query for projectnumber

$query_1 = "SELECT PROJECTNOID, ProjectNumber, ProjectTitle, (SELECT (SELECT 
     CustomerName FROM tblCustomers WHERE Customer = CUSTOMERID) AS Customer 
     FROM tblCustomerContacts WHERE CustomerProjectLeadID = 
     CUSTOMERCONTACTID) AS CustomerProjectLeadID  FROM tblProjects ORDER BY 
     ProjectNumber DESC";

$result_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query_1);
$options_1 = "";

while($row_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1))
{
   $options_1.='<option value="'.$row_1[0].'">'.$row_1[1]." - ".$row_1[2]." - ".$row_1[3].'</option>';
}

?>
```

further down this page I have the following html

```
<label>Project Number <b style="color:red;">*</b></label>
<select id="proj" name="projectnum" class="inputvalues" required>
<option disabled selected value>-- Project # - Title - Customer --</option>
   <?php echo $options_1; ?>
</select><br>

<div id="currentnumpo">
<label>Number of POs</label><input name="numpos" class="inputvalues" id="reqtxtfield" readonly/><br>
</div>
```

and after the closing html tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#proj").on('change', function() {
    var num = $(this).val();
    if(num){
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getnumberpo.php',
            data: { num },
            success : function(htmlresponse) {
                $('#currentnumpo').html(htmlresponse);
                console.log(htmlresponse);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

My "getnumberpo.php"

```
<?php
echo $_POST['projectnum'];
if(isset($_POST['projectnum'])){
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblCustomerPOs WHERE ProjectNum = '".$_POST['projectnum']."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($sql) {
    while($row = $conn->query($sql)) {
        echo '<label>Number of POs</label><input name="numpos" class="inputvalues" id="reqtxtfield" placeholder="';
        echo $row[0];
        echo '" readonly/><br>';
    }
}
$sql = NULL;
}

?>
```

I'm very new to javascript/ajax so i'm sorry if none of what i'm doing makes sense.

So far when I change the dropdown the whole textbox for "number of po's" dissappears. I've ran the query on "getnumberpo.php" on mysql workbench and it works just fine.

Ex: When I select a project from the dropdown. It will query another table called tblCustomerPOs and check how many rows contain the project number that was selected.

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is getting printed in the console for `console.log(htmlresponse);`

Comment: @new_user nothing gets posted

Comment: change `data: { num }` to `data: { projectnum : num }` you need to send key value pair. so when you are fetching it as `$_POST['projectnum']` you get data.

Comment: @new_user after doing this the console outputs `POST [website] 500 (Internal Server Error)` with  `jquery-3.3.1.js:9600` beside it

Comment: it means there is an error in your backend code.

Comment: are you making a connection in `getnumberpo.php` to use `$conn`?

Comment: @new_user I wasn't initially but after adding it I still get the same error. Could it be a problem with how i'm echoing the query?

Comment: try this, right click -> inspect -> click on network tab -> click on XHR. now you can see when ever there is a request and response the server is written. you may see the error.

Comment: @new_user in the response tab im getting `<label>Number of POs</label><input name="numpos" class="inputvalues" id="reqtxtfield" value="` without the other two echo statements.

Comment: what is the response type you are getting? try debugging you are in the right path.

Comment: @new_user --> [Inspect debugging](https://imgur.com/a/ZERuMwv) <-- Here is everything displayed in the console. I tried putting all the info into one echo statement and the response got nothing instead of the first statement that it had before. I think the error is with `echo $row[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this in the future and wanted the answer...

getnumberpo.php (Server-Side Script)

```
<?php
 require "../inc/dbinfo.inc";

 $projectnum =$_POST['projectnum'];
 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS mycount FROM tblCustomerPOs WHERE ProjectNum = '$projectnum'"); //RESPONSE IS QUERY WITH REAL $PROJECTNUM
 $res = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)
 $count = $res->mycount;
 echo json_encode($count);
 exit();
?>
```

new-customer-po.php (Javascript)

```
//AUTO UPDATE NUMBER OF POS
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#projectnum').change(function(){
     var projectnum = $(this).val();
     var data_String;
     data_String = 'projectnum='+projectnum;
     $.post('getnumberpo.php',data_String,function(data){
     var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     $('#currentnumpo').val(data)
     });
  });
});
```

new-customer-po.php (html)

```
<label>Project Number <b style="color:red;">*</b></label>
<select id="projectnum" name="projectnum" class="inputvalues" required>
   <option disabled selected value>-- Project # - Title</option>
   <?php echo $options_1; ?>
</select><br>

<label>Number of Customer POs</label><input type="text" name="currentnumpo"  id="currentnumpo" class="inputvalues" readonly/><br>
```